# Django - Encrypt a whole model instance

Tags: python, django, encryption

I'm currently figuring out what would be the best way to encrypt an instance of a model in Django.

[Encrypting single fields seems easy](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/), but I would like to encrypt a whole **instance**.

**Context**

I'm currently building a note-taking application which should have the ability to optionally encrypt a note using a given password.

The model looks something like this:

```py
class Note(models.Model):
    title = CharField()
    content = TextField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    edited_at = DateTimeField()
    parent = ForeignField("note.Note")
```

While I could simply only encrypt the `title` and `content`, I don't want that to avoid telling any information about a note when it is encrypted. So basically all fields (event `created_at` and `edited_at`) should be encrypted.

**Thoughts**

I thought about adding a second model `EncryptedNote` which only holds a field `encrypted_data`. This field contains the data in a JSON format in an encrypted form.
When the application needs to load the instance, it will decrypt the content and create a `Note` instance based on the JSON data.

However, it feels a little bit off to manually save JSON when using a SQL-like database.

**Question**

Is there already a good (and secure) way to encrypt an instance or is this idea of manually encrypting and decrypting the data using JSON a good approach?